# ERROR 1114 (HY000) at line 3352: The table 'table_name' is full | import not working in vagrant mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, vagrant, mysql-workbench

I am receiving below error when I am trying to import from SQL dump file.

I am using MySQL in vagrant box.

[image]

Comment: no help from standard documentation ? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/table-size-limit.html

Comment: Reading the above doc, I think the most obvious reason for getting the message is probably the good one on a local vm in vagrant importing some dev data: `the disk is full`